# Difficulties Selecting from a Local Variable Using a Another Local Variable in the Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to find the most recent table to have been updated. Most of the tables in the server have a column named something like 'lastmodified'.

My approach in this was to try to select all the tablenames (and corresponding columnnames which are like '%lastmodified%') and run them through a loop.

The loop is meant to select the max lastmodified date from each table.

I have been playing around with the EXEC statement in order to have the select statement pull from the local variable @tablename.

```
SELECT      c.name columnname
            ,t.name tablename
into #looptemp
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%lastmodified%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName

alter table #looptemp add 
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)

alter table #looptemp add 
lastmod date

declare @run INT
declare @column varchar(1028)
declare @tablename varchar(1028)
declare @datein date

set @run = 1

while (@run <= (select Max(ID) from #looptemp))
Begin

set @column = (Select columnname from #looptemp where ID = @run)
set @tablename =  (select '(''' + tablename + ''')' from #looptemp where ID = @run) 
set @datein = EXEC('SELECT max(@column) FROM ' + @tablename)

update #looptemp set lastmod = @datein

set @run =@run + 1
End
```

Without the Execute line: "Must declare the variable @tablename"
With the EXEC line I get a syntax error and the equal sign before the EXEC is highlighted.

Comment: `set @datein = EXEC(..)` is wrong syntax. What are you trying to do in this line? Look at sp_executesql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am trying to select the Maximum last edit date for each table name and store it in @datein. The end result I'm aiming for is for the temp table the max last modified date added for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sp_executesql. Your logic is not quite clear to me, try

```
SELECT      c.name columnname
            ,t.name tablename
into #looptemp
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%lastmodified%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName

alter table #looptemp add 
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)

alter table #looptemp add 
lastmod date

declare @run INT
declare @column varchar(1028)
declare @tablename varchar(1028)
declare @datein date

set @run = 1

while (@run <= (select Max(ID) from #looptemp))
Begin

set @column = (Select columnname from #looptemp where ID = @run)
set @tablename =  (select  tablename from #looptemp where ID = @run) 
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT @d = max('+ @column + ') FROM ' + @tablename;
--print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@d date out', @d=@datein out;

update #looptemp set lastmod = @datein 
where ID = @run;

set @run =@run + 1
End
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43fb93dafd443c57e228447b0ad0f8a1)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - Thanks!